# BigInteger, как увеличить вводимую строку?

Tags: java, biginteger

Имеется число с = 2 в степени 77232917. И хочу записать это число в BigInteger a = new BigInteger("с");
Но длина строки ограничена, можно как то увеличить её?

Comment: э, в смысле "ограничена"? откуда вы это взяли? покажите свой код.

Comment: сложно будет вставить это число ), я просто посчитал 2^7723917 и это число вставил в new BigInteger("число"),  при компиляции пишет что слишком длинная строка.

Comment: из файла пробовали читать это число?

Comment: пока не пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить искомое `BigInteger` (ведь вам просто нужно получить новый объект `BigInteger` содержащий некое число 2^7723917, так?) вы можете воспользоваться операцией возведения в степень

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("2").pow(77232917);
```

или для для случая 2^xx операцией побитового сдвига

```
BigInteger big2  = new BigInteger("1").shiftLeft(77232917);
```

Comment: Спасиб, я так и делал, просто хотел вставить число вручную, т.к расчет его был где-то 1~ минута на моем компе, а так все норм.

Comment: При выводе на консоль долго висит, но если замерить время выполнения самой операции, то у меня вышло 9 и 7 мс соответственно. Не думаю что ради уменьшения этих значений стоит что либо предпринимать) Тем более парсинг из десятичного числа вряд ли будет быстрее операции битового сдвига.